# Fill all data from database in dataTable and build a list

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, datatable, datarelation

I have 2 objects  like this:

```
public class Place : ICloneable, IEquatable<Place>
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public float longitude{ get; set; }
    public float latitude{ get; set; }
    public Horizon thehorizon  { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class Horizon
{
    public List<PointF> points{ get; set; }
}
```

In my database I have 2 tables - "places" and "horizons", with a foreign key in horizons to know to which place the points belongs.

So the structure of the places is:

1. Name -nvarchar - primary key
2. longitude - real
3. latitude - real

and the structure of the horizons is

1. parent_key - nvarchar
2. pointX - real
3. poinY - real

I wrote the code below to select all the data and build a list of place. It's working, but it's very slow. If you have any suggestion how to make it faster (or any comment), please tell me.

```
DataTable TablePlaces;
DataTable TableHorizons;

public void init()
{
    TablePlaces = new DataTable();
    TablePlaces.Columns.Add("Name");
    TablePlaces.Columns.Add("longitude");
    TablePlaces.Columns.Add("latitude");

    TableHorizons = new DataTable();
    TableHorizons.Columns.Add("parent_key");
    TableHorizons.Columns.Add("pointX");
    TableHorizons.Columns.Add("pointY");

    System.Data.DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    DS.Tables.Add(TablePlaces);
    DS.Tables.Add(TableHorizons);
    DS.Relations.Add(TablePlaces.Columns["Name"],
        TableHorizons.Columns["parent_key"]);
}

public List<Place> BuilsListPlace()
{
    TableHorizons.Clear();
    TablePlaces.Clear();
    using (DbCommand Command = newConnectionNewCommand())
    {
        Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM places ORDER BY Name"
        fill(TablePlaces, Command);
        Command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM horizons ORDER BY parent_key,pointX";
        fill(TableHorizons, Command);

        Command.Connection.Dispose();
    }
    return (from DataRow dr in TablePlaces.Rows
            select newPlace(dr)).ToList();
}

void fill(TableDB t ,DbCommand Command)
{
    using (var da = newDataAdapter())
    {
        da.SelectCommand = Command;
        da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.Ignore;
        da.Fill(t);
    }
} 
Place newPlace(DataRow dr)
{
    Place result = new Place();
    result.longitude=(float)dr["longitude"];
    result.latitude=(float)dr["latitude"];
    result.Name=(string)dr["Name"];
    result.theHorizon=newHorizon(dr.GetChildRows(dr.Table.ChildRelations[0]));
    return result;
}

Horizon newHorizon(DataRow[] Rows)
{
    Horizon result = new Horizon();
    result.points = new List<PointF>();
    foreach(DataRow dr in Rows)
        result.points.Add(new PointF((float)dr["pointX"],(float)dr["pointY"]);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How many records do you have in those tables? Are we speaking of hundreds, thousands or millions? Loading everything into memory and THEN do stuff is not that optimal, I'd say.

Comment: I have 1800 places and about 800 point in an horizon, but only 20 places have horizon, all the rest have 0 points. if I don't do it that way - how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This extension I found for converting `datatable` to `list of objects` using reflection & generic, but keep in mind that the property name has to be exact the same with the one in datatable

Hope it helps

```
public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
{
    try
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
        {
            T obj = new T();

            foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                try
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            list.Add(obj);
        }

        return list;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did a similar function too. but you didn't include the child tables, so if one of the properties is listed in another table - it will not work.

Comment: TablePlaces = new DataTable();
TablePlaces.Columns.Add("Name");
TablePlaces.Columns.Add("longitude");
TablePlaces.Columns.Add("latitude");

TableHorizons = new DataTable();
TableHorizons.Columns.Add("parent_key");
TableHorizons.Columns.Add("pointX");
TableHorizons.Columns.Add("pointY");

In your code, I did not see any child table, but you're right. Anyway, in term of performance, if you have too many data in 1 table, you might want to consider to implement paging logic. And you should add some indexes in your table in order to boost the selection speed. Cheers!

Comment: At this point I'd rather have a look at Entity Framework Code First - rather than trying to re-invent the wheel using Reflection and whatnot. It might seem overwhelming at first, but it really helps as it does a lot of work for you out of the box.

Comment: `Code First` or `Database First` is the same in this situation. I think you were trying to say use `ORM` like `Entity Framework` :)

Comment: Yeah ... true that. I am only using Code First recently so it still sticks to me for the countless Google searches I've done =)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to select only the things that you really need. Although you say you have about 1800 places (which should not be a problem at all)... Try with the following

```
public IList GetPlaces()
{
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection("blahblahblah"))
  {
    conn.Open();
    var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT p.Name, h.pointX, h.pointY FROM places p LEFT OUTER JOIN horizons h ON h.parent_key = p.Name";

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

    using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      tbl.Load(rdr);

    return tbl.Rows
      .Cast<DataRow>()
      .Select(r => new
        {
          Name = r.Field<string>("Name"),
          HorizonX = r.Field<float>("pointX"),
          HorizonY = r.Field<float>("pointY")
        }).ToList();
  }
}
```

The "Select" part below is returning an anonymous type and not the types you were looking for. But it should not be hard to go from here, and converting it to you classes suing Select / SelectMany a.s.o.

Note that it is not really important *how you return your data to a List*, but it's pretty important *how you read it from the database*.

Comment: I don't understand for what the `JOIN`. since we select all the data in the table - the query is simple - `SELECT *` and it give me the same result, because `parent_key` is your `p.Name`

Comment: any way. it will not by any faster. I think the problem is not in the query, but in the dataTable, it's take 3.5 seconds to fill it

Comment: Before trying anything else: Have you tried to call "BeginLoadData" before bulk-loading? It disables all constraint checks for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it now. it's better, but still very long.

Comment: If it was 3.5sec befor how much is it now? "Better" translates to something around 2.0sec for me which might be reasonable considering connection overhead among other thigns. But then again I don't know much about your infrastructure, where your server stands etc...

Comment: it is now 2.75 sec. and the database is in a file in my computer. when I don't use the dataTable and I read the reader directly in object[] with reader.GetValues() it take 0.4 sec!  but then I can't use the datarelation and I must on any place do a query in the list of points (16,000 points) to find the point witch belong to this particular place, and this query is very very slow (a query on 1800*16,000 items)

Comment: That is exactly where a the JOIN comes in handy. You could try to not match those entities with a DataTable, but let the DB flat it out for you and then join it usin LINQ or something along the line.